# How to properly use dataloaders across multiple users?

Tags: node.js, caching, graphql

In [caching per request](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader#caching-per-request) the following example is given that shows how to use dataloaders in express.

```
function createLoaders(authToken) {
  return {
    users: new DataLoader(ids => genUsers(authToken, ids)),
  }
}

var app = express()

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var authToken = authenticateUser(req)
  var loaders = createLoaders(authToken)
  res.send(renderPage(req, loaders))
})

app.listen()
```

I'm confused about passing `authToken` to `genUsers` batch function. How should a batch function be composed to use `authToken` and to return each user corresponding results??

Answer (score 1):

What the example is saying that `genUsers` should use the credentials of the current request's user (identified by their auth token) to ensure they can only fetch data that they're allowed to see. Essentially, the loader gets initialised at the start of the request, and then discarded at the end, and never recycled between requests.